# Grouping the results in an array having same name

Tags: python, python-2.x

`results` is a list of dict having panel name and work type and price to do that work on that panel. There can be two dicts for same name and work type where one of them is on car model level and another is on car type level. In such cases we would give preference to car model level dict.

`output` is the group of panels and prices per work type (removing the prices on car type if car model price exist for same panel and work type combination).

```
results = sorted(results, key=lambda datum: datum['car_model'])

#removing the car type if car model exists.
d = defaultdict(dict)
for l in results:
    d[l['name']+'-'+l['work_type']] = l

results = d.values()

#grouping the results at panel level.
d = defaultdict(dict)
for l in results:
    d.setdefault(l['name'],[]).append(l)

#creating dict such that panel name is key and price_list is array of all the panel prices.
output = []
for key,value in d.iteritems():
    output.append({"name":key,"price_list":value})
```

---

Example input:

```
results = [
        {
            "id":1,
            "car_type":1,
            "car_model":None,
            "name":"Door",
            "work_type":"Dent",
            "price":2300,
        },
        {
            "id":2,
            "car_type":1,
            "car_model":None,
            "name":"Door",
            "work_type":"Scratch",
            "price":1200,
        },
        {
            "id":3,
            "car_type":None,
            "car_model":2,
            "name":"Door",
            "work_type":"Dent",
            "price":2500,
        },
        {
            "id":4,
            "car_type":1,
            "car_model":None,
            "name":"Fender",
            "work_type":"Dent",
            "price":2300,
        },
        {
            "id":5,
            "car_type":1,
            "car_model":None,
            "name":"Fender",
            "work_type":"Scratch",
            "price":1300,
        }
    ]
```

Expected output:

```
[{'name': 'Fender',
  'price_list': [{'car_model': None,
    'car_type': 1,
    'id': 5,
    'name': 'Fender',
    'price': 1300,
    'work_type': 'Scratch'},
   {'car_model': None,
    'car_type': 1,
    'id': 4,
    'name': 'Fender',
    'price': 2300,
    'work_type': 'Dent'}]},
 {'name': 'Door',
  'price_list': [{'car_model': 2,
    'car_type': None,
    'id': 3,
    'name': 'Door',
    'price': 2500,
    'work_type': 'Dent'},
   {'car_model': None,
    'car_type': 1,
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'Door',
    'price': 1200,
    'work_type': 'Scratch'}]}]
```

Comment: Yes. The `output` is expected output but I have removed few fields from `output` to make it short. Updated the question with correct output.

Comment: Won't defining `car_model` as `None` result in an error when doing `results = sorted(results, key=lambda datum: datum['car_model'])` ?

Comment: Not in python 2.7. Although it will give error in Python 3

Answer (score 3):

## General comments

```
results = sorted(results, key=lambda datum: datum['car_model'])
```

Good use of `sorted`!

```
#removing the car type if car model exists.
d = defaultdict(dict)
for l in results:
    d[l['name']+'-'+l['work_type']] = l

results = d.values()
```

Why are you using a `defaultdict`? A normal `dict` suffices.

```
#grouping the results at panel level.
d = defaultdict(dict)
for l in results:
    d.setdefault(l['name'],[]).append(l)
```

Again, why a `defaultdict`, a normal dict suffices.

```
#creating dict such that panel name is key and price_list is array of all the panel prices.
output = []
for key,value in d.iteritems():
    output.append({"name":key,"price_list":value})
```

Good enough, I suppose. Alternatively, use

```
output = [{"name": key, "price_list": value} for key, value in d.iteritems()]
```

## Variable naming

Variable names such as `d` and `l` just don't cut it anymore. Please use descriptive variable names.

## Revised code

```
results = sorted(results, key=lambda datum: datum['car_model'])

# Make sure results are unique by {name}-{work_type}
results = {l['name'] + '-' + l['work_type']: l for l in results}.values()

# Grouping the results at panel level.
d = {}
for l in results:
    d.setdefault(l['name'],[]).append(l)

# Creating dict such that panel name is key and price_list is array of all the panel prices.
output = [{"name": key, "price_list": value} for key, value in d.iteritems()]
```

## Separate by functions

I see several actions: getting unique values, grouping by a key, and finally outputting it.

### Getting unique values

```
def unique_by(lst, key=lambda x: x):
    return {key(v): v for v in lst}.values()
```

You can call it like

```
results = unique_by(results, key=lambda l: l['name'] + '-' + l['work_type'])
```

or better

```
results = unique_by(results, key=lambda l: (l['name'], l['work_type']))
```

and using `operator.itemgetter`:

```
results = unique_by(results, key=itemgetter('name', 'work_type'))
```

### Grouping by a key

```
def group_by(lst, key=None):
    assert key is not None, 'You must supply a key function'
    retval = {}
    for v in lst:
        retval.setdefault(key(v), []).append(v)
    return retval
```

You can call it like

```
grouped = group_by(results, key=lambda l: l['name'])
```

or

```
grouped = group_by(results, key=itemgetter('name'))
```

## Revised, again

```
from operator import itemgetter

results = sorted(results, key=itemgetter('car_model'))
results = unique_by(results, key=itemgetter('name', 'work_type'))
grouped = group_by(results, key=itemgetter('name'))
output = [{"name": name, "price_list": items} for name, items in grouped.iteritems()]
```

(where `unique_by` and `group_by` are defined as above.)

Note: untested, but it should work (modulo syntax errors).